# Cannot assign to read only property ERROR

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update value of record in list at record level and getting above error.

I understand that lists are read only, and we need to create a copy of it, before we can make any changes to record/object level properties.

So, say below is the structure of my data

```
lstMyData =   [{Property1 : 'val', Property2: 'val2' , lstData : [{...}, {...}]} , {..} ] ;
```

Now, the data is returned from back-end and I initially create a copy of it using:

```
lstTemp = lstMyData.map( obj => ({
                ...obj
              }));
```

If I make changes to any property of any record in **lstTemp** it works pretty well. However, if I try to make changes to any of the properties of records in **lstData** , I get the above error.

How do I fix this?

Edit:
[image]

Here's a sample structure of my data.. sComment, sOpptName, sQuote, etc are part of my records which are dynamically passed to front-end to be displayed on web component. Now, each record also has a list of Comments displayed under it.

I have provided the user ability to edit comments provided by them under individual records. When I try to update the value of sComment property under lstComments I get error : **Cannot assign to read only property**

As mentioned above I understand this error occurs when the list is in read only mode, and to avoid such errors on top level list, I created a copy of original list using the mechanism highlighted above.

Now, when I try to make changes to any of the property values in lstComments, this error pops - up. I made a copy of the original list of records.

What else do I do initially so that **lstComments** records are copied as well and I don't get this error.

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of what you're doing that is causing an error? Also, can you clean up your structure? `Property 2` is not a valid key, and I'm assuming you should have a comma between the faked entries in `lstData`

Comment: @rfestag I've updated the question.

Comment: Please include the actual code that is generating the error message. Most likely your syntax isn't doing what you think it's doing.